# Как изменить версию javascript в браузере Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Здравствуйте, каким образом можно понизить/изменить стандарт языка с ES6 на ES5 в последних версиях браузера Chrome?

Comment: Никак. Новые браузера уже выходят со встроенным ES6. Нужно качать старую версию браузера

Comment: а зачем это может понадобиться?

Comment: Хочу в Chrome тестировать работу кода на ES5 стандарте. Можно это делать и в IE переключаясь, скажем, на 8 версию, но там уж очень неудобно работать.

Comment: @МаксимЖелезняков, во-первых IE8 es5 стандарт не сказать чтобы хорошо поддерживал. Во-вторых, если Вы встроите этап транспиляции сильно париться по этому поводу не нужно будет.